# Laravel - permission and roles package?

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, package, roles

is there any package, in which can i create more complex role and permission hierarchy?

I have a lot of companies, that can log into a system. Each company has a superadmin, who can create another accounts for own company. These accounts will be in superadmin/admin/user roles. Superadmin of each company can set a different permissions for their roles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This package can be used in Laravel 5.4 or higher. If you are using an older version of Laravel, take a look at the v1 branch of this package.

You can install the package via composer:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: yeah i know this package but i dont know how Can i use it for my problem.. i need to make own set of permissions for each company.. this package can make just global roles  and permissions for all

Comment: Thank you for your acknowledgement.

You need to define roles in **roles** table as well as permissions in **permissions** table and assign that roles to users after that you can easily check which user is belong to which role and assign them particular part role and permission wise.

You need to set query and assign **Parent_id** for each company's user.When any company create new role and permission and assign to user then it automatically follow that role and permission structure.